# Best way to compare LocalDates

Tags: date, java-8

I have two `LocalDate` objects. I want to find out how many days there are between two events:

```
if(Math.abs(userBirthday - eventDate) <= 5)
    // give discount
```

Do you have any suggestions how to do it in a most sophisticated way?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution, please confirm that it's correct way of doing this:

```
Math.abs(userBirthday.toEpochDay() - eventDate.toEpochDay()) >= 5
```

Comment: Look at the linked question with the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

From memory of JodaTime you can do something like this

```
Days.daysBetween(startLocalTime, endLocalTime).getDays()
```

(not 100% on this Im afraid - Im on a machine without a compiler)

Comment: Nope, this does work. Try it on dates on different months, you'll see ;)

Comment: @Tunaki The answer is correct for Joda-Time. The only mistake is that it is not related to what the OP asked for.(see his java-8-tag).